# Create a relation

Tags: sql

I have no idea about how to create relation and solve their queries. I want to relation as follows:

```
BookAuthor(book, author, earnings)
BookReference(book, referenceBook, times)
BookReview(book, reviewer, score)
BookPublih(book, year, publisher, price, numbar)
```

In these database, each book may have 1 or more authors & each author may make a diff. amt. of money from that book. One book may make reference to other book.1 book may be reviewed by diff. reviewers and get diff. scores. an author could also be a reviewer & a publisher.

I want to solve following queries

1. Find all books published in 2003 & reviewed by both Sammer Tulpule & Hemant Mehta.
2. Find all the reviewers who never reviewed their own books.
3. Find all authors who reviewed more than 2 books written by Sita Mitra.
4. Find all authors who have written exactly 1 book and reviewed more than 1 book.
5. Find all the reviewer who reviewed every book from 'Stephen King'.
6. Find all books published in 1995-2000 in descending order.

I know, these is not good to find an answer, but believe me i really don't under

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem could use these tables:

`BOOKS (BookID, BookName,PubDate,PublisherPerson_ID,Price,Number)` //stores each book and its data

`PERSONS(PersonID, Name)` //stores any people (authors, reviewers)

`BOOKAUTHORS(Book_ID, Person_ID)` //many to many relationship between books and authors

`BOOKREVENUE(Book_ID, Person_ID, Revenue)` //stores revenue for each book per author

`BOOKREFERENCES(Book_ID, RefBook_ID)` //many to many reference table for books

`BOOKREVIEWERS(Book_ID, Person_ID, Score)` //many to many relationship for book reviews

Im not going to write the queries here, but this will get you started

Comment: what i understand from your reply is that, BOOKS and PERSONS are simple tables as follows. 1. CREATE TABLE BOOKS(BooKID INTEGER, BooksName VARCHAR(20), PubDate DATETIME, PublisherPersonID INTEGER, Price INTEGER, Number INTEGER) AND 2.CREATE TABLE PERSONS(PersonID INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(20)). And other are relationship, but how to create that relationship?     Am I right?

Comment: Yes kind of, the ID with underscores (_ID) in them are know as Foreign Keys. In your DBMS you can specify that these integers are foreign keys to another table, effectively creating a relationship between them